# C++ WriteFile doesn't work when writting big sectors, getLastError return 5

Tags: c++, operating-system, filesystems, writefile

I have a problem with my code. I try to write to sector but it's only work for sector < 4500. But i want to write to sector 8192 and getLastError return 5 (Access denied) for me. How can I do that?
Here's my WriteSector function:

```
void WriteSector(LPCWSTR drive, int numSector, BYTE sector[512]) {
    DWORD bytesRead;
    HANDLE device = NULL;

    device = CreateFile(drive,    // Drive to open
        GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE,           // Access mode
        FILE_SHARE_READ | FILE_SHARE_WRITE,        // Share Mode
        NULL,                   // Security Descriptor
        OPEN_EXISTING,          // How to create
        0,                      // File attributes
        NULL);                  // Handle to template

    if (device == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
    {
        printf("CreateFile: %u\n", GetLastError());
        return;
    }

    SetFilePointer(device, numSector * 512, NULL, FILE_BEGIN);

    if (!WriteFile(device, sector, 512, &bytesRead, NULL))
    {
        printf("WriteFile: %u\n", GetLastError());
    }
    else
    {
        printf("Success!\n");
    }  
}
```

and testing:

```
int sector_RDET = numSector_BootSector + num_FAT_table * FAT_size;

    ReadSector(drive, sector_RDET, sector);

    int n = number_of_files_in_directory("H:/");

    if (n % 2 != 0) {
        for (int i = 0; i < 2*n+1; i+=2) {
            sector[160 + (4 * 16) * i] = 70;
        }
    }

    WriteSector(drive, sector_RDET, sector);
```

Comment: `printf("WriteFile: %u\n", GetLastError());` -- Don't call `GetLastError()` this way.  Save the last error in a variable, i.e. `DWORD lastError = GetLastError();`.  The reason is that the intervening call to `printf` may trigger an internal function that resets the last error flag.

Comment: What? May printf be sequenced before GetLastError? Could you refer to the standard?

Comment: There are two arguments to the `printf` call.  I was burned by this in the past, where I assumed that GetLastError() will remain as-is in a multi-argument function call as the parameter.  Rather than risking it, better to save the value right away.

Comment: I deleted prinf and try again. But it's still not work for sector 8192. Sector <4500 still be ok :(

Comment: @Paul A function call in another argument was a reason in your case. It's impossible in this case.

Comment: I was denied access to the part of the disk that contained a volume that was in use, not all.